# How to get a distinct list in post order (last value)?

Tags: c#, linq

`.Distinct()` returns distinct values of a list in order, I.e. `1,2,3,1` becomes `1,2,3`.

I want to get the distinct values of a last but always return the last value instead of the first - how would i do that?

```cs
var input = new List<string> { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA" };

//input = input
//    .Distinct()
//    .ToList(); 
// Returns: "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"

//input = input
//    .GroupBy(c => c)
//    .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(x => x).Last())
//    .ToList();
// Returns: "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"

// TEST
var output = new List<string> { "BBB", "CCC", "AAA" };

if (input.SequenceEqual(output))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fail!");
}
```

Comment: Try `input.Reverse(); input = input.Distinct().ToList(); input.Reverse();`. There's no built-in LINQ operator that does what you want. If you want to avoid modifying the original list, other than to reassign it back into the input variable, you can do `input = Enumerable.Reverse(Enumerable.Reverse(input).Distinct()).ToList();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lasse v. Karlsen pointed out, reversing the string running a distinct and reversing the string again works.

```cs
input.Reverse();
input = input
    .Distinct()
    .Reverse()
    .ToList();
```

Just be mindful that 2 different `.Revers()` calls are used: `List<T>.Reverse()` and `Enumerable.Reverse(source)` (Linq).